# Fetching YouTube videos from API able to display through button Onclick, need to display on page not through button click want directly on my page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, youtube-iframe-api, jsonresult

Not able to display youtube videos on my webpage directly in reactjs, only able to do it through Onclick Button, but i dont need any button to be clicked for getting videos on my page, i want videos to be diplayed directly on my webpage after fetching data, try by changing code but not able to find solution, i am new on coding, any changes need to be done on code to get videos displayed on webpage without clicking.

```
const finalURL = `https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=${ChannelID}&maxResults=${result}&key=${API}`

class Youtube extends Component {
    
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    
        this.state = {
            resultyt: []
        };

        this.Clicked= this.Clicked.bind(this);
    }

    Clicked() {
    fetch (finalURL)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
const resultyt = responseJson.items.map(obj => "https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+obj.id.videoId);
this.setState({resultyt});

    })
.catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
})



    }
    
    render() {

        return (

<div>
    <button onClick={this.Clicked}>
        My Channel Videos
        </button>
    {
            this.state.resultyt.map((link,i) => {
                var frame = <div key={i} className='Guru'><iframe width="200" height="100" src={link} frameBorder="0" allowFullScreen></iframe> </div>
        return frame;
            })
        }
    
    
{this.frame}
    
    
</div>


            )
        }
    }
    
    



export default Youtube
```

Comment: put the body of Clicked() in componentDidMount and it should work

Comment: i want to remove button and just need to display videos from fetched data, instead of clicked function anything else needed.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `componentDidMount`. More information here: https://en.reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html